# How do I add django-sitegate to a template or existing page?

Tags: django, wagtail

I have been following the wagtail tutorial [here](https://blog.michaelyin.info/2017/06/26/wagtail-tutorials/), and have a basic site setup with a few other packages installed and configured.

However, while attempting to add in django-sitegate to have user registration and login functionality, I have had nothing but trouble. I am following the sitegate quick example here, which is identical to the instructions in the quick start guide in the documentation.

So, I added the following to the top of my models.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from sitegate.decorators import sitegate_view
```

And I included the following within my 'BlogPage' model in models.py:

```
@sitegate_view  # This also prevents logged in users from accessing our sign in/sign up page.
def entrance(request):
    return render(request, 'entrance.html', {'title': 'Sign in & Sign up'})
```

I then appended the following to my blog_page.html template:

```
{% extends "blog_page.html" %}
{% load sitegate %}

{% block page_contents %}
    <div class="my_signin_block">
        {% sitegate_signin_form %}
    </div>
    <div class="my_signup_block">
        {% sitegate_signup_form %}
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Which gives the error

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /blog/
<ExtendsNode: extends "blog_page.html"> must be the first tag in the template.
```

So when I move the extends line to the top of the file, it works, but a blank html page is returned, with basic bootstrap code to adjust to viewport, and a single empty div.

However when putting the template code in it's own file, site_gate.html, I get a 404 error when trying to access it via blog/site_gate.html

I did a recursive grep for blog_page.html through my site and can't seem to find where the template for a view or model is defined. I'm not sure how to add my site_gate template to the list of templates.

I am trying to get a simple sitegate registration page working to eventually be able to include it in a modal in my blog_page.html template.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by "appended to the template"? You do not add an `{% extend %}` tag directly in the file its suppose to inherit from but in its own template. You then call this child template from your view.

I don't know your file structure but, usually, you will have a folder `<your_app_name>` that contains your models.py, views.py, etc. In that folder, you create a `Template` folder and a `<your_app_name>` folder inside of it, which will contain your app's templates.

```
my_app
|
--- Template
|     |
|     --- my_app
|          |
|          --- a_template.html
---models.py
---views.py
...
```

your my_app.views.py

```
@sitegate_view  # This also prevents logged in users from accessing our sign in/sign up page.
    def entrance(request):
        return render(request, 'my_app/a_template.html', {'title': 'Sign in & Sign up'})
```

your my_app.url.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'my_app'
urlpatterns = [
    path('some_name/', views.entrance, name='some_name'),
]
```

and make sure your app's urls are included in the `<name_of_your_project>` folder

your `<name_of_your_project>`.urls.py must include:

```
from django.urls import include
...
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('my_app/', include('my_app.urls')),
    ...
]
```

So now when you access www.myawsomesite/my_app/some_name/ it will call your `entrance` view, which will render and return a_template.html.

Comment: Thank you for explaining! The documentation was not clear to me, although rereading it with your answer it seems it should have been. I made your changes, although had to change path references to url. Thank you again for explaining!